# Laravel excel export into excel table

Tags: php, mysql, excel, laravel, export-to-excel

I'm new to Laravel and i'm trying to export to excel sheet every ticket created for the past 7 days starting from current day into an excel table with headers.

my excelexport code in TicketsController is :

```
public function exportxls(){
    $weeklyTickets = \App\Tickets::whereBetween('created_at', array(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-7 days")), date('Y-m-d')))->get();

    Excel::create('tickets', function($excel) use ($weeklyTickets){
      $excel->sheet('tickets', function($sheet) use ($weeklyTickets){
        $sheet->loadView('export.ticketsexcel', array('weeklyTickets' => $weeklyTickets));
      })->export('xls');
    });
    return redirect('/');
  }
```

My Tickets export view is:

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Nom de la société</td>
    <td>Intervenant</td>
    <td>Type D'assistance</td>
    <td>Objet</td>
    <td>Urgence</td>
    <td>Statut</td>
    <td>Utilisateur</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>


  @foreach ($weeklyTickets as $ticket)
    <tr>
    <td>{{ $ticket->societe}}</td>
    <td>{{ $ticket->intervenant}}</td>
    <td>{{ $ticket->assistance->level}}</td>
    <td>{{ $ticket->message}}</td>
    <td>{{ $ticket->urgence->niveau}}</td>
    <td>{{ $ticket->statut}}</td>
    <td>{{ $ticket->utilisateur->name}}</td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach

</tbody>
</table>
```

Can you help me figure out why it only exports 1 ticket instead of all tickets of the past 7 days, and why it doesn't make it into an excel table in the sheet?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I figured out the query part, now i don't know how to make it into a proper excel table. Any help?

Comment: If you're trying to export an XLS file, why is there HTML in your question?